# When router usage and when inner views, especially in Backbone/Require apps

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Should Backbone routers be used for nested views also, as it it is used for navigating in between more complete page views and some other sorts? When to use a router and when to use inner views?

For example a home view page has tabs and each tab for showing another view with its model and collection. This home view is similar to Twitter or Facebook. How should this complete page be rendered:

1. By navigating via router to subviews on tab clicks and rendering by subviews render function and placing them in home view page by homeview render, or routers is not and not good for this purpose. Advantage: a.bookmark-able subviews, b. ?more maintainable code. Disadvantage: on page refresh homeview part not rendered, only subview does.
2. Instead, on tab clicks subviews should be created in homeview and
   rendered in themselves and placed in the home view page by homeview
   render(). Advantage: no disadvantage above. Disadvantage: no advantage a, ?b above.

UPDATE:

3. A hybrid solution to refresh problem in 1. To have each subview to render homeview parts, tabs etc., by depending on a seperte single little template for that or from their templates having written those parts code to have those homeview parts. Disadvantage here is like separation of modules decreases a bit by subviews requiring (as dependancy) or including (in their template) something that is not sub at all but something like sup, main, belongs to an upper level module.

Or is there another, better, way?

Comment: Did anybody read this, know answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately it's subjective; there is no rule for when you should start a new page View triggered by a `Backbone.Router` route and when you should just re-render a sub-view for a part of the DOM without involving a route.  Really, it's just a matter of whether you want the user to feel like they've gone to a new page or not.  Ask yourself:

- do you want them to be able to click back/forward in their browser?
- do you want them to be able to bookmark the "page"?
- is most of the DOM changing or just a small part?

To put it another way, when a user goes to a `Backbone.Router` page it indicates that a significant change in state has occurred on your site.  Really all the bookmarking/history entry/significant DOM changes are just reflections of that.  So if you feel that a significant change, whatever that means to you and your site, is happening, make a route for it.  Otherwise just re-render a `View`.

Comment: Is it not undesirable for any app/website not to be able to render if somehow somebody refreshed the page? This is case I face if I use Router. Or I do not know to overcome this refresh issue and use routers at the same time. In my app this pages exist together in the DOM and they just come to the screen by a full page slide(if do not try to implement otherwise i.e. they are fetched every time). It has the feel of the same page inbetween sliding.Answers to three questions are almost totally no for each.I was just trying to attain best practices.Thought it was use of routers here,as controller.

Comment: I'm confused: what "refresh issue" are you referring to?  One of the points of using the `Router` and creating a route for your "page" is so that the user can return to that "page" when they refresh.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't think of the `Router` as *the* controller.  From the Backbone site: " If it helps any, in Backbone, the View class can also be thought of as a kind of controller, dispatching events that originate from the UI, with the HTML template serving as the true view. We call it a View because it represents a logical chunk of UI, responsible for the contents of a single DOM element."  In other words, a `Backbone.View` is not just the V in MVC, and the `Router` is just one piece of the overall controller for your site.

Comment: I refer to the case: While using routers show those subview parts, when I refresh after I click tab of homeview to show the subview whole page as intended, the route to it in router is reached so its corresponding method, which creates a subview instance and call render of it from inside router. But in general, first, the app is loaded with home view before it reaches a point it shows a subview upon a click event to navigate to subviews route, and it already have rendered its, homeview, own parts like title bar and navbar that includes clickable tabs to show the subviews.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble understanding you, but I *think* what you're referring to is the issue of: 1) most of your site loads, 2) the `Router` handles the route, 3) your page sub-view renders a part of your page.  Because of that, your users see part of the site load, then see the rest of it.  Is that the issue?

Comment: I both couldn't understand and explained it clearly.Lets say I have a homeview, whole page.A mainrouter directed me to that homeview at the beginning.Homeview has tabs.Clicking tabs should show a subview by a method in homeview navigating by mainrouter.Subviews are whole width under tabbar.After navigated, url has been updated. now subview is shown in the place I wrote.If at this stage one refreshes the page,this same stage is not reached.Because of the url, directly the router will route to the method to render the subview but where to put it in dom.homeview is not there with its element.

Comment: First off, this sounds like a separate issue, so it probably would make more sense to ask it as a new Stack Overflow question.  That being said, it sounds like an issue with how you're rendering your page.  If your code is not rendering the main page when someone hits reload, or if it renders the main page after the sub-page is rendered, then you just need to change your render code.  For instance, maybe you want to add a `renderPage` method to your `Router`, and have it generate the main page before generating the sub-page.  Then you can just have all of your routes call that method.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will collect it and ask as a seperate question. By the way it some times renders correctly sometimes not.